# Arithmetic and Conditional Expression evaluator in ios (contains String and Values)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have three examples in which i have to evaluate expression, Examples as follows,

1. `(x + y +30)`
2. `((p == "Good") && (q == "Morning")) || (r == "10:00")`
3. `((w == "Night") && ( (a + b +30) >100 ) )`

Here `x`, `y` ,`a`, and `b` are integers and `p`, `q`, `r`, and `w` are Strings.

For #1 I used the DDMathParser library but for #2 and 3 we cannot because DDMathParser does not allow String evaluation.

Requirement is any library or example source code that evaluates above expression contains String and Values.

Please help me to evaluate it.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You can do like this if([p isEqualToString:@"Good"] && ([q isEqualToString:@"Morning"])) || ([r isEqualToString:@"10:00"]))
    {
        
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of these are parseable using `NSPredicate` or `NSExpression`. You could use `@try...@catch` statements to try and run them through `+[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:]` or `+[NSExpression expressionWithFormat:]` and see which one works.

Once you've done that, you could evaluate them against an `NSDictionary` and see what happens. For example:

```
NSString *formula = @"((w == \"Night\") && ( (a + b +30) >100 ) )";
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:formula];
NSDictionary *object = @{
                         @"w": @"Night",
                         @"a": @42,
                         @"b": @33
                         };

BOOL passes = [p evaluateWithObject:object];
NSLog(@"passes: %@", passes ? @"yes" : @"no"); // logs "yes"
```

Comment: Thanks Dave. I have one more question,  NSString *formula = @"form_component_1?lower_case?contains(\"boa\")" . Where form_component_1 as input variable. Am not able to predicate this. Please help me do evaluate this.